# Django custom through table for ManyToMany relationship: save method not being called during model form save (or save_m2m)

Tags: django, python-3.x, database

Here's the setup...

```
class RequestUserBaseClass(Model):
    # There is middleware that sets "thread.request" with each request - that is functioning fine
    thread = threading.local()

    created_by = ForeignKey(User)

    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_by = RequestUserBaseClass.thread.request.user
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class CustomThroughTable(RequestUserBaseClass):
    ...

class SimpleModelClass(RequestUserBaseClass):
    ...
    manyfield = ManyToManyField(OtherTable, through=CustomThroughTable)
    ...

class SimpleModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SimpleModelClass
        fields = [... 'manyfield' ... ]
```

in a view...

```
if simple_form.is_valid():
    simple_form.save()
```

Bottom line: I have this base class, it sets the created by field by working together with some custom middleware that puts the user in a thread local variable. Works great, use it all over the place.

Then I have a model with a `ManyToManyField` that uses a custom through table. When the form gets saved, I get an integrity error about `created_by_id` not being set, and from inspecting the output it is when the entry in the through table is being added into the database. This lines up because I only get the error when the `ManyToManyField` has been edited. If I do `simple_form.save(commit=False)` and then call `simple_form.save_m2m()` separately then I get the `IntegrityError` exception on the `save_m2m()` call.

Why would this be though? Would `save()` not be getting called when that through table entry is added or something?

Feel free to ask for more info if you think you need it for some reason. I'm available and stumped...

**Update:**

*I confirmed that `save()` is not being called on the custom through table model (just added a `raise Exception('DEBUG')` and it was never hit). I suppose this just means I need to manually save my m2m fields rather than using the `ModelForm#save()` method. At this point I guess I'm just wondering if any Django gurus agree with this approach or think its a Django bug I'm hitting.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, never could confirm whether this was a Django bug or not, but I did manage to solve (probably workaround really) the issue. Basically just had to do the following in the view:

```
if simple_form.is_valid():
    form_data = deepcopy(simple_form.cleaned_data)

    # pop out m2m
    manyfield = form_data.pop("manyfield", [])

    # set non m2m fields
    for key, val in form_data.items():
        setattr(simple_model_instance, key, val)

    # Need to create through entries directly so that the throughclass#save()" gets called and sets created_by
    for manyentry in manyfield:
        CustomThroughTable.objects.get_or_create(...)

    simple_model_instance.save()
```

Essentially: manually apply the form data to the existing instance, then manually create the custom through table entries so that their save method would get called (and in my specific example, thus call the abstract parent's save method and set the created_by attribute)